# Майка, май — этимология

Tags: этимология

Действительно ли слово "майка" образовано от названия месяца "май"?

Не знаю, как конец мая, но уж начало-то для майки точно рановато.

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли кто скажет, что там было в действительности, словари наши тоже разного мнения.

Крылов Г. А. утверждает:

> Ма́йка. Название этой рубашки без рукавов, возможно, было заимствовано
>   из французского в 30-е годы XX в. Франц. maillot «футболка, майка».
>   По другой этимологической версии, майка — «одежда, которую начинают
>   носить в мае».

М.Фасмер:

> ма́йка ["рубашка спортивного типа". Очевидно, от май; см. ВЯ, 1960, №
>   3, стр. 64. — Т.]

Шанский:

> Заимств. в XX в. из итал. яз., где maglia «майка» того же корня, что
>   франц. maille «петля», mailler«взять». Словообразовательно
>   переоформлено с помощью суф. -к(а). Первоначально — «вязаная
>   футболка». Связь с май вторична.

https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0

Мне ближе объяснение Шанского. А что до того, что майку носят в мае - почему бы и нет? Разный май бывает, бывает и жара. Может, когда это слово к нам пришло, как раз и была жара, майки носили, ассоциации людей вполне логичны: май-майка, а что это заимствование, никто и не задумывался, совпало же...